# Getting multiple values from Aerospike with SpringData

Tags: spring-data, aerospike

I want to fetch multiple data using Aerospike Repositories. I have defined a method:

```
List<Profile> findByIds(List<String> profilekeys, Class<Profile> class1);
```

And trying to use it as:

```
 profileRepository.findByIds(profilekeys, Profile.class);
```

The Profile is:

```
@Id
private String id;
private String obj;
```

But, I am getting issues like:

> No property ids found for type Profile! Did you mean 'id'?

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: This looks like a call in some framework, rather than you using the Aerospike client for Java.  The Java client can do [batch reads](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,%20com.aerospike.client.Key[])) (as can all the other clients).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The method I was looking for is: `Iterable<Profile> profileList = profileRepository.findAll(keys);`. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using Aerospike repository, explained here: https://www.aerospike.com/blog/spring-data-for-aerospike/

Comment: Might as well write that up as the answer and get yourself some points.